# Can't access images in upload folder using Express and multer

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, multer

I have an application built on Node/Express/Angular.

I have all my angular front end code in a "client" folder and I have all my backend (nodejs & express) in another folder ("server").

I use Grunt to compile the code into the "server/dist" folder, so when I publish to production, I'm just uploading the "server" folder.

I've added a feature to upload images and am using multer to do that.

I've created an "fileuploads" folder in the "server" directory and am successfully uploading files to that folder.

The Problem:

In my app I need to reference the images, but even though I've created a static reference in my server/app.js file, I'm still unable to reach them.

Here is what my server side app.js file looks like:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var cors = require('cors');
var multer = require('multer');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/OM');

var app = express();

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors());    

app.use('/api', require('./routes/api'));
app.use('/sendmail', require('./routes/sendmail'));
app.use('/uploads', require('./routes/uploads'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/app/custom')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/fileuploads')));



// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});

app.all('/*', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/dist/index.html'));
});

module.exports = app;
```

On the client side, I've tried accessing the files in the following way:

```
<img src="fileuploads/0d904f4a422ea5a8fcd9a3859b58cdb9" />

<img src="/fileuploads/0d904f4a422ea5a8fcd9a3859b58cdb9" />

<img src="../fileuploads/0d904f4a422ea5a8fcd9a3859b58cdb9" />
```

But nothing seems to work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7):

It will be nice to have

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/fileuploads')));
```

as

```
app.use('/fileuploads', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/fileuploads')));
```

or make it shorter this way:

```
app.use('/fileuploads', express.static(process.cwd() + '/fileuploads'));
```

That way, you will be able to access it anywhere in your app as: 
`<img src="/fileuploads/0d904f4a422ea5a8fcd9a3859b58cdb9" />` which is basically saying "anywhere i call fileuploads, serve me the right path". ^_^